# Можно ли перегрузить свойство класса?

Tags: delphi, ооп, классы

Есть класс, в котором хотелось бы объявить property, возвращающее различный тип переменной, в зависимости от типа:

```
  TGenomeData = class
    private
<...>
      function GetGeneArray:GeneArray;
      function GetRepeatsArray:RepeatsArray;
<...>
    public
      property ChrData[chr,pos:integer] : GeneArray read GetGeneArray;
      property ChrData[chr,pos:integer] : RepeatsArray read GetRepeatsArray;
<...>
  end;
```

Т.е., фактически, перегрузить это свойство класса. Но, увы, на такое объявление компилятор ругается "Заново объявлен идентификатор", попытка добавить ключевое слово `overload` тоже успеха не даёт.
Возможны ли вообще перегруженные свойства классов в Delphi?

Comment: нет, overload не применим к свойствам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формально, нельзя - синтаксис языка запрещает подобные конструкции. Но, если нельзя, но очень хочется, то можно, но не совсем полноценно.
Для этого нужно воспользоваться ключевым словом default. Оно, формально, служит не для этого, но в данном случае заставляет компилятор не обращать внимание на повторную декларацию переменной. И... всё работает как надо, но только в том случае, если chr или pos, или обе сразу в объявлении второго свойства будут другого типа. Например, pos для второго можно объявить, как int64. Правда, в этом случае вы теряете возможность использовать константы для индексирования, плюс обязаны либо использовать для индекса переменную int64, либо выполнять приведения типа.

В вашем случае это будет так:

```
TGenomeData = class
    private
<...>
      function GetGeneArray:GeneArray;
      function GetRepeatsArray:RepeatsArray;
<...>
    public
      property ChrData[chr,pos:integer] : GeneArray read GetGeneArray; default;
      property ChrData[chr:integer; pos:int64] : RepeatsArray read GetRepeatsArray; default; // поскольку, если правильно понимаю, к хромосоме вы будете обращаться через константу, а вот позиция чаще задаётся переменной.
<...>
  end;
```

Тогда вы можете обращаться к первому элементу как угодно, т.е. ChrData[1,500], ChrData[1,i] и т.п. а вот ко второму только так: ChrData[1, int64(i)] или ChrData[1, k], где k - обязательно int64. Не факт, что вам будет удобно.

Есть ещё подход, связанный с наследованием:

```
 type
     TGenomeData = class
       <...>
       property ChrData[chr,pos:integer] : GeneArray read GetGeneArray; 
     end;

     TNewGenomeData = class(TGenomeData)
       ...
       property ChrData[chr,pos:integer] : RepeatsArray read GetRepeatsArray; 
     end;
```

В этом случае свойство потомка скроет свойство предка. В зависимости от того, конструктор какого класса вы вызвали, вы будете получать доступ к тому или иному свойству. Если вам это достаточно, то - как вариант.

Comment: С наследованием несколько нехорошо и дело не в конструкторе: допустим, есть `TList<TGenomeData>`, в котором содержатся в перемешку `TGenomeData` и `TNewGenomeData`. Чтобы получить доступ к новому свойству - потребуется явное кастование: `TNewGenomeData(List[i])[1,3]` с обязательной проверкой перед этим - а допустимо ли такое приведение типа вообще.
На мой взгляд автор вопроса хочет сделать то, что приведет потом к его же головной боли.

Comment: @kami В этом случае - да. Но тут ТС должен сам объяснить, будут ли данные у него перемешаны, или же каждый экземпляр будет работать лишь с одним типом данных, а ему просто лень создать два класса :)

Comment: Спасибо! Первый вариант вполне мне подойдёт: позицию по хромосоме я всегда отлавливаю по переменной, задать явный тип, пожалуй, будет проще, чем описывать два варианта источника данных. А наследование - не мой конёк :)